# Registration timeout on PBS cluster with Ipython parallel

Tags: python, parallel-processing, cluster-computing, ipython, pbs

I'm trying to set up ipython parallel on a linux cluster using PBS scheduling.

I was following instructions at http://www.andreazonca.com/2013/04/ipython-parallell-setup-on-carver-at.html (the official instructions are much harder to follow). I'm running the command on the head node, which sends the jobs to the slave nodes with PBS (ie, a standard cluster configuration).

My problem is that I get a timeout. I tried increasing the waiting time from 2s up to 20s but without success. Any help would be appreciated. Full output is below.

Actually, in the end I want to be able to run the ipython commands from my ssh-connected laptop rather than from the cluster-head-node, but I thought this was a reasonable first step.

```
2013-08-11 13:56:07,380.380 [IPEngineApp] Config changed:
2013-08-11 13:56:07,381.381 [IPEngineApp] {'EngineFactory': {'timeout': 10}, 'IPEngineApp': {'log_level': 10}}
2013-08-11 13:56:07,381.381 [IPEngineApp] Config changed:
2013-08-11 13:56:07,382.382 [IPEngineApp] {'EngineFactory': {'timeout': 10}, 'IPEngineApp': {'log_level': 10}}
2013-08-11 13:56:07,381.381 [IPEngineApp] Config changed:
2013-08-11 13:56:07,381.381 [IPEngineApp] Config changed:
2013-08-11 13:56:07,383.383 [IPEngineApp] {'EngineFactory': {'timeout': 10}, 'IPEngineApp': {'log_level': 10}}
2013-08-11 13:56:07,382.382 [IPEngineApp] Config changed:
2013-08-11 13:56:07,382.382 [IPEngineApp] Config changed:
2013-08-11 13:56:07,383.383 [IPEngineApp] {'EngineFactory': {'timeout': 10}, 'IPEngineApp': {'log_level': 10}}
2013-08-11 13:56:07,382.382 [IPEngineApp] Config changed:
2013-08-11 13:56:07,383.383 [IPEngineApp] {'EngineFactory': {'timeout': 10}, 'IPEngineApp': {'log_level': 10}}
2013-08-11 13:56:07,383.383 [IPEngineApp] {'EngineFactory': {'timeout': 10}, 'IPEngineApp': {'log_level': 10}}
2013-08-11 13:56:07,383.383 [IPEngineApp] {'EngineFactory': {'timeout': 10}, 'IPEngineApp': {'log_level': 10}}
2013-08-11 13:56:07,382.382 [IPEngineApp] Config changed:
2013-08-11 13:56:07,383.383 [IPEngineApp] {'EngineFactory': {'timeout': 10}, 'IPEngineApp': {'log_level': 10}}
2013-08-11 13:56:07,387.387 [IPEngineApp] Using existing profile dir: u'/home/username/.ipython/profile_default'
2013-08-11 13:56:07,387.387 [IPEngineApp] Searching path [u'/home/username', u'/home/username/.ipython/profile_default'] for config files
2013-08-11 13:56:07,388.388 [IPEngineApp] Attempting to load config file: ipython_config.py
2013-08-11 13:56:07,388.388 [IPEngineApp] Using existing profile dir: u'/home/username/.ipython/profile_default'
2013-08-11 13:56:07,388.388 [IPEngineApp] Searching path [u'/home/username', u'/home/username/.ipython/profile_default'] for config files
2013-08-11 13:56:07,389.389 [IPEngineApp] Attempting to load config file: ipython_config.py
2013-08-11 13:56:07,389.389 [IPEngineApp] Using existing profile dir: u'/home/username/.ipython/profile_default'
2013-08-11 13:56:07,389.389 [IPEngineApp] Searching path [u'/home/username', u'/home/username/.ipython/profile_default'] for config files
2013-08-11 13:56:07,389.389 [IPEngineApp] Attempting to load config file: ipython_config.py
2013-08-11 13:56:07,389.389 [IPEngineApp] Loaded config file: /home/username/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py
2013-08-11 13:56:07,389.389 [IPEngineApp] Using existing profile dir: u'/home/username/.ipython/profile_default'
2013-08-11 13:56:07,389.389 [IPEngineApp] Attempting to load config file: ipengine_config.py
2013-08-11 13:56:07,389.389 [IPEngineApp] Searching path [u'/home/username', u'/home/username/.ipython/profile_default'] for config files
2013-08-11 13:56:07,389.389 [IPEngineApp] Attempting to load config file: ipython_config.py
2013-08-11 13:56:07,389.389 [IPEngineApp] Using existing profile dir: u'/home/username/.ipython/profile_default'
2013-08-11 13:56:07,389.389 [IPEngineApp] Loaded config file: /home/username/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py
2013-08-11 13:56:07,389.389 [IPEngineApp] Loaded config file: /home/username/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py
2013-08-11 13:56:07,389.389 [IPEngineApp] Attempting to load config file: ipengine_config.py
2013-08-11 13:56:07,389.389 [IPEngineApp] Searching path [u'/home/username', u'/home/username/.ipython/profile_default'] for config files
2013-08-11 13:56:07,389.389 [IPEngineApp] Using existing profile dir: u'/home/username/.ipython/profile_default'
2013-08-11 13:56:07,389.389 [IPEngineApp] Attempting to load config file: ipython_config.py
2013-08-11 13:56:07,389.389 [IPEngineApp] Attempting to load config file: ipengine_config.py
2013-08-11 13:56:07,390.390 [IPEngineApp] Searching path [u'/home/username', u'/home/username/.ipython/profile_default'] for config files
2013-08-11 13:56:07,390.390 [IPEngineApp] Attempting to load config file: ipython_config.py
2013-08-11 13:56:07,390.390 [IPEngineApp] Loaded config file: /home/username/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py
2013-08-11 13:56:07,390.390 [IPEngineApp] Loaded config file: /home/username/.ipython/profile_default/ipengine_config.py
2013-08-11 13:56:07,390.390 [IPEngineApp] Using existing profile dir: u'/home/username/.ipython/profile_default'
2013-08-11 13:56:07,390.390 [IPEngineApp] Loaded config file: /home/username/.ipython/profile_default/ipengine_config.py
2013-08-11 13:56:07,390.390 [IPEngineApp] Attempting to load config file: ipengine_config.py
2013-08-11 13:56:07,390.390 [IPEngineApp] Loaded config file: /home/username/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py
2013-08-11 13:56:07,390.390 [IPEngineApp] Searching path [u'/home/username', u'/home/username/.ipython/profile_default'] for config files
2013-08-11 13:56:07,390.390 [IPEngineApp] Attempting to load config file: ipython_config.py
2013-08-11 13:56:07,390.390 [IPEngineApp] Loaded config file: /home/username/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py
2013-08-11 13:56:07,390.390 [IPEngineApp] Attempting to load config file: ipengine_config.py
2013-08-11 13:56:07,390.390 [IPEngineApp] Attempting to load config file: ipengine_config.py
2013-08-11 13:56:07,390.390 [IPEngineApp] Loaded config file: /home/username/.ipython/profile_default/ipengine_config.py
2013-08-11 13:56:07,390.390 [IPEngineApp] Using existing profile dir: u'/home/username/.ipython/profile_default'
2013-08-11 13:56:07,390.390 [IPEngineApp] Searching path [u'/home/username', u'/home/username/.ipython/profile_default'] for config files
2013-08-11 13:56:07,391.391 [IPEngineApp] Attempting to load config file: ipython_config.py
2013-08-11 13:56:07,391.391 [IPEngineApp] Loaded config file: /home/username/.ipython/profile_default/ipengine_config.py
2013-08-11 13:56:07,391.391 [IPEngineApp] Loaded config file: /home/username/.ipython/profile_default/ipengine_config.py
2013-08-11 13:56:07,391.391 [IPEngineApp] Loaded config file: /home/username/.ipython/profile_default/ipengine_config.py
2013-08-11 13:56:07,391.391 [IPEngineApp] Loaded config file: /home/username/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py
2013-08-11 13:56:07.391 [IPEngineApp] Loading url_file u'/home/username/.ipython/profile_default/security/ipcontroller-engine.json'
2013-08-11 13:56:07,391.391 [IPEngineApp] Loaded config file: /home/username/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py
2013-08-11 13:56:07.391 [IPEngineApp] Loading url_file u'/home/username/.ipython/profile_default/security/ipcontroller-engine.json'
2013-08-11 13:56:07,391.391 [IPEngineApp] Attempting to load config file: ipengine_config.py
2013-08-11 13:56:07.391 [IPEngineApp] Loading url_file u'/home/username/.ipython/profile_default/security/ipcontroller-engine.json'
2013-08-11 13:56:07,391.391 [IPEngineApp] Attempting to load config file: ipengine_config.py
2013-08-11 13:56:07,392.392 [IPEngineApp] Loaded config file: /home/username/.ipython/profile_default/ipengine_config.py
2013-08-11 13:56:07.392 [IPEngineApp] Loading url_file u'/home/username/.ipython/profile_default/security/ipcontroller-engine.json'
2013-08-11 13:56:07.392 [IPEngineApp] Loading url_file u'/home/username/.ipython/profile_default/security/ipcontroller-engine.json'
2013-08-11 13:56:07.392 [IPEngineApp] Loading url_file u'/home/username/.ipython/profile_default/security/ipcontroller-engine.json'
2013-08-11 13:56:07,392.392 [IPEngineApp] Loaded config file: /home/username/.ipython/profile_default/ipengine_config.py
2013-08-11 13:56:07.392 [IPEngineApp] Loading url_file u'/home/username/.ipython/profile_default/security/ipcontroller-engine.json'
2013-08-11 13:56:07.393 [IPEngineApp] Loading url_file u'/home/username/.ipython/profile_default/security/ipcontroller-engine.json'
2013-08-11 13:56:07.402 [IPEngineApp] Registering with controller at tcp://127.0.0.1:53956
2013-08-11 13:56:07.402 [IPEngineApp] Registering with controller at tcp://127.0.0.1:53956
2013-08-11 13:56:07.402 [IPEngineApp] Registering with controller at tcp://127.0.0.1:53956
2013-08-11 13:56:07.402 [IPEngineApp] Registering with controller at tcp://127.0.0.1:53956
2013-08-11 13:56:07.403 [IPEngineApp] Registering with controller at tcp://127.0.0.1:53956
2013-08-11 13:56:07.403 [IPEngineApp] Registering with controller at tcp://127.0.0.1:53956
2013-08-11 13:56:07.403 [IPEngineApp] Registering with controller at tcp://127.0.0.1:53956
2013-08-11 13:56:07.403 [IPEngineApp] Registering with controller at tcp://127.0.0.1:53956
2013-08-11 13:56:01,273.273 [IPEngineApp] Config changed:
2013-08-11 13:56:01,273.273 [IPEngineApp] Config changed:
2013-08-11 13:56:01,274.274 [IPEngineApp] {'EngineFactory': {'timeout': 10}, 'IPEngineApp': {'log_level': 10}}
2013-08-11 13:56:01,274.274 [IPEngineApp] {'EngineFactory': {'timeout': 10}, 'IPEngineApp': {'log_level': 10}}
2013-08-11 13:56:01,272.272 [IPEngineApp] Config changed:
2013-08-11 13:56:01,274.274 [IPEngineApp] Config changed:
2013-08-11 13:56:01,275.275 [IPEngineApp] {'EngineFactory': {'timeout': 10}, 'IPEngineApp': {'log_level': 10}}
2013-08-11 13:56:01,275.275 [IPEngineApp] {'EngineFactory': {'timeout': 10}, 'IPEngineApp': {'log_level': 10}}
2013-08-11 13:56:01,273.273 [IPEngineApp] Config changed:
2013-08-11 13:56:01,276.276 [IPEngineApp] {'EngineFactory': {'timeout': 10}, 'IPEngineApp': {'log_level': 10}}
2013-08-11 13:56:01,276.276 [IPEngineApp] Config changed:
2013-08-11 13:56:01,276.276 [IPEngineApp] {'EngineFactory': {'timeout': 10}, 'IPEngineApp': {'log_level': 10}}
2013-08-11 13:56:01,278.278 [IPEngineApp] Config changed:
2013-08-11 13:56:01,278.278 [IPEngineApp] {'EngineFactory': {'timeout': 10}, 'IPEngineApp': {'log_level': 10}}
2013-08-11 13:56:01,279.279 [IPEngineApp] Using existing profile dir: u'/home/username/.ipython/profile_default'
2013-08-11 13:56:01,279.279 [IPEngineApp] Using existing profile dir: u'/home/username/.ipython/profile_default'
2013-08-11 13:56:01,279.279 [IPEngineApp] Searching path [u'/home/username', u'/home/username/.ipython/profile_default'] for config files
2013-08-11 13:56:01,279.279 [IPEngineApp] Attempting to load config file: ipython_config.py
2013-08-11 13:56:01,279.279 [IPEngineApp] Searching path [u'/home/username', u'/home/username/.ipython/profile_default'] for config files
2013-08-11 13:56:01,279.279 [IPEngineApp] Using existing profile dir: u'/home/username/.ipython/profile_default'
2013-08-11 13:56:01,279.279 [IPEngineApp] Attempting to load config file: ipython_config.py
2013-08-11 13:56:01,280.280 [IPEngineApp] Searching path [u'/home/username', u'/home/username/.ipython/profile_default'] for config files
2013-08-11 13:56:01,280.280 [IPEngineApp] Attempting to load config file: ipython_config.py
2013-08-11 13:56:01,280.280 [IPEngineApp] Using existing profile dir: u'/home/username/.ipython/profile_default'
2013-08-11 13:56:01,280.280 [IPEngineApp] Searching path [u'/home/username', u'/home/username/.ipython/profile_default'] for config files
2013-08-11 13:56:01,280.280 [IPEngineApp] Using existing profile dir: u'/home/username/.ipython/profile_default'
2013-08-11 13:56:01,280.280 [IPEngineApp] Config changed:
2013-08-11 13:56:01,280.280 [IPEngineApp] Attempting to load config file: ipython_config.py
2013-08-11 13:56:01,280.280 [IPEngineApp] Searching path [u'/home/username', u'/home/username/.ipython/profile_default'] for config files
2013-08-11 13:56:01,280.280 [IPEngineApp] Loaded config file: /home/username/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py
2013-08-11 13:56:01,280.280 [IPEngineApp] {'EngineFactory': {'timeout': 10}, 'IPEngineApp': {'log_level': 10}}
2013-08-11 13:56:01,280.280 [IPEngineApp] Loaded config file: /home/username/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py
2013-08-11 13:56:01,280.280 [IPEngineApp] Attempting to load config file: ipython_config.py
2013-08-11 13:56:01,280.280 [IPEngineApp] Attempting to load config file: ipengine_config.py
2013-08-11 13:56:01,280.280 [IPEngineApp] Loaded config file: /home/username/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py
2013-08-11 13:56:01,280.280 [IPEngineApp] Attempting to load config file: ipengine_config.py
2013-08-11 13:56:01,281.281 [IPEngineApp] Attempting to load config file: ipengine_config.py
2013-08-11 13:56:01,281.281 [IPEngineApp] Loaded config file: /home/username/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py
2013-08-11 13:56:01,281.281 [IPEngineApp] Attempting to load config file: ipengine_config.py
2013-08-11 13:56:01,281.281 [IPEngineApp] Loaded config file: /home/username/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py
2013-08-11 13:56:01,281.281 [IPEngineApp] Loaded config file: /home/username/.ipython/profile_default/ipengine_config.py
2013-08-11 13:56:01,281.281 [IPEngineApp] Loaded config file: /home/username/.ipython/profile_default/ipengine_config.py
2013-08-11 13:56:01,281.281 [IPEngineApp] Using existing profile dir: u'/home/username/.ipython/profile_default'
2013-08-11 13:56:01,281.281 [IPEngineApp] Loaded config file: /home/username/.ipython/profile_default/ipengine_config.py
2013-08-11 13:56:01,281.281 [IPEngineApp] Searching path [u'/home/username', u'/home/username/.ipython/profile_default'] for config files
2013-08-11 13:56:01,281.281 [IPEngineApp] Attempting to load config file: ipengine_config.py
2013-08-11 13:56:01,281.281 [IPEngineApp] Loaded config file: /home/username/.ipython/profile_default/ipengine_config.py
2013-08-11 13:56:01,281.281 [IPEngineApp] Attempting to load config file: ipython_config.py
2013-08-11 13:56:01,282.282 [IPEngineApp] Loaded config file: /home/username/.ipython/profile_default/ipengine_config.py
2013-08-11 13:56:01,282.282 [IPEngineApp] Loaded config file: /home/username/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py
2013-08-11 13:56:01,282.282 [IPEngineApp] Attempting to load config file: ipengine_config.py
2013-08-11 13:56:01,282.282 [IPEngineApp] Using existing profile dir: u'/home/username/.ipython/profile_default'
2013-08-11 13:56:01.282 [IPEngineApp] Loading url_file u'/home/username/.ipython/profile_default/security/ipcontroller-engine.json'
2013-08-11 13:56:01,282.282 [IPEngineApp] Searching path [u'/home/username', u'/home/username/.ipython/profile_default'] for config files
2013-08-11 13:56:01.282 [IPEngineApp] Loading url_file u'/home/username/.ipython/profile_default/security/ipcontroller-engine.json'
2013-08-11 13:56:01,282.282 [IPEngineApp] Attempting to load config file: ipython_config.py
2013-08-11 13:56:01.282 [IPEngineApp] Loading url_file u'/home/username/.ipython/profile_default/security/ipcontroller-engine.json'
2013-08-11 13:56:01,283.283 [IPEngineApp] Loaded config file: /home/username/.ipython/profile_default/ipengine_config.py
2013-08-11 13:56:01,283.283 [IPEngineApp] Loaded config file: /home/username/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py
2013-08-11 13:56:01,283.283 [IPEngineApp] Attempting to load config file: ipengine_config.py
2013-08-11 13:56:01,284.284 [IPEngineApp] Using existing profile dir: u'/home/username/.ipython/profile_default'
2013-08-11 13:56:01,284.284 [IPEngineApp] Loaded config file: /home/username/.ipython/profile_default/ipengine_config.py
2013-08-11 13:56:01,284.284 [IPEngineApp] Searching path [u'/home/username', u'/home/username/.ipython/profile_default'] for config files
2013-08-11 13:56:01,284.284 [IPEngineApp] Attempting to load config file: ipython_config.py
2013-08-11 13:56:01.284 [IPEngineApp] Loading url_file u'/home/username/.ipython/profile_default/security/ipcontroller-engine.json'
2013-08-11 13:56:01.284 [IPEngineApp] Loading url_file u'/home/username/.ipython/profile_default/security/ipcontroller-engine.json'
2013-08-11 13:56:01.284 [IPEngineApp] Loading url_file u'/home/username/.ipython/profile_default/security/ipcontroller-engine.json'
2013-08-11 13:56:01.284 [IPEngineApp] Loading url_file u'/home/username/.ipython/profile_default/security/ipcontroller-engine.json'
2013-08-11 13:56:01,284.284 [IPEngineApp] Loaded config file: /home/username/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py
2013-08-11 13:56:01,285.285 [IPEngineApp] Attempting to load config file: ipengine_config.py
2013-08-11 13:56:01,286.286 [IPEngineApp] Loaded config file: /home/username/.ipython/profile_default/ipengine_config.py
2013-08-11 13:56:01.286 [IPEngineApp] Loading url_file u'/home/username/.ipython/profile_default/security/ipcontroller-engine.json'
2013-08-11 13:56:01.295 [IPEngineApp] Registering with controller at tcp://127.0.0.1:53956
2013-08-11 13:56:01.295 [IPEngineApp] Registering with controller at tcp://127.0.0.1:53956
2013-08-11 13:56:01.296 [IPEngineApp] Registering with controller at tcp://127.0.0.1:53956
2013-08-11 13:56:01.296 [IPEngineApp] Registering with controller at tcp://127.0.0.1:53956
2013-08-11 13:56:01.296 [IPEngineApp] Registering with controller at tcp://127.0.0.1:53956
2013-08-11 13:56:01.296 [IPEngineApp] Registering with controller at tcp://127.0.0.1:53956
2013-08-11 13:56:01.298 [IPEngineApp] Registering with controller at tcp://127.0.0.1:53956
2013-08-11 13:56:01.299 [IPEngineApp] Registering with controller at tcp://127.0.0.1:53956
2013-08-11 13:56:17.411 [IPEngineApp] Registration timed out after 10.0 seconds
2013-08-11 13:56:17.412 [IPEngineApp] Registration timed out after 10.0 seconds
2013-08-11 13:56:17.413 [IPEngineApp] Registration timed out after 10.0 seconds
2013-08-11 13:56:17.412 [IPEngineApp] Registration timed out after 10.0 seconds
2013-08-11 13:56:17.412 [IPEngineApp] Registration timed out after 10.0 seconds
2013-08-11 13:56:17.413 [IPEngineApp] Registration timed out after 10.0 seconds
2013-08-11 13:56:17.413 [IPEngineApp] Registration timed out after 10.0 seconds
2013-08-11 13:56:17.413 [IPEngineApp] Registration timed out after 10.0 seconds
2013-08-11 13:56:11.304 [IPEngineApp] Registration timed out after 10.0 seconds
2013-08-11 13:56:11.304 [IPEngineApp] Registration timed out after 10.0 seconds
2013-08-11 13:56:11.305 [IPEngineApp] Registration timed out after 10.0 seconds
2013-08-11 13:56:11.306 [IPEngineApp] Registration timed out after 10.0 seconds
2013-08-11 13:56:11.306 [IPEngineApp] Registration timed out after 10.0 seconds
2013-08-11 13:56:11.306 [IPEngineApp] Registration timed out after 10.0 seconds
2013-08-11 13:56:11.307 [IPEngineApp] Registration timed out after 10.0 seconds
2013-08-11 13:56:11.309 [IPEngineApp] Registration timed out after 10.0 seconds
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun noticed that the job aborted, but has no info as to the process
that caused that situation.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Update following advice from Andrea Zonca**

Adding

```
c.HubFactory.ip = '*'
```

appears to help, although not immediately for some unknown reason.

But it still doesn't work:

I run with

```
./.ipython/profile_default/ipc 2 1

2013-09-09 12:19:51,884.884 [IPClusterStart] Using existing profile dir: u'/home/username/.ipython/profile_default'
2013-09-09 12:19:51.889 [IPClusterStart] Starting ipcluster with [daemon=False]
2013-09-09 12:19:51.890 [IPClusterStart] Creating pid file: /home/username/.ipython/profile_default/pid/ipcluster.pid
2013-09-09 12:19:51.890 [IPClusterStart] Starting Controller with LocalControllerLauncher
2013-09-09 12:19:52.890 [IPClusterStart] Starting 2 Engines with PBS
2013-09-09 12:19:52.904 [IPClusterStart] Job submitted with job id: '4783'
2013-09-09 12:20:22.904 [IPClusterStart] Engines appear to have started successfully
```

and then run on the head node:

```
>IPython.parallel import Client
>rc = Client()
>lview = rc.load_balanced_view()
```

but the output from

```
>rc.ids
```

is

```
[]
```

So I tried running

```
ipcontroller --port=8888
```

and then run nmap

```
$nmap -sT -O localhost
...
8888/tcp  open  sun-answerbook
...
```

which shows the port is open, and sure-enough telnet gives me a response from the slave node.

But when I run the original command above
ie,

```
./.ipython/profile_default/ipc 2 1
```

nmap shows no port as being open. So the problem appears to be that ipengine run in the qsub file is not opening the port like ipcontroller run from the command line is.

Here is the qsub file:

```
$cat /home/username/.ipython/profile_default/pbs.engine.template.ppn2 
#!/bin/sh
#PBS -q longqueue
#PBS -l nodes={n/2}:ppn=2
cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR
which ipengine
mpirun -np {n} ipengine --timeout=20
```

and here is my /home/username/.ipython/profile_default/ipcluster_config.py:

```
c = get_config()

c.IPClusterStart.controller_launcher_class = 'LocalControllerLauncher'
c.IPClusterStart.engine_launcher_class = 'PBS'
c.PBSLauncher.batch_template_file = u'/home/username/.ipython/profile_default/pbs.engine.template'
```

Comment: can you post also the terminal log after you run the `ipc` script? the `PBS` script has nothing to do with the controller, the controller is just run locally on the login node. The `pbs` script just launches the engines.

Comment: try change: `c.IPClusterStart.controller_launcher_class = 'LocalControllerLauncher'` to `c.IPClusterStart.controller_launcher_class = 'Local'`

Answer (score 1):

You need to allow connections to the controller from other hosts, setting  in `~/.config/ipython/profile_default/ipcontroller_config.py`:

```
c.HubFactory.ip = '*'
```

Btw, I also updated the blog post.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion, but despite reporting the correct IP address now (instead of 127.0.0.1) it doesn't work. Maybe my head node doesn't allow random ports to be opened? I'm not sure. I guess normally Head-node -- Slave-node connection is rsh. Is there a simple way around this, or do I have to figure out how to open select ports to the slave nodes? Thanks a lot for your comment though - it took me a step further!

Comment: Try manually, launch the controller, then telnet on its port locally from the login node. Then create an interactive job, and telnet from the compute node to the login and check you can connect.

Comment: Thanks, one step closer but still not there yet. There was no telnet on any of the nodes, and after I installed it on the head node, suddenly there was no timeout any more! But, performing from IPython.parallel import Client, rc = Client(), lview = rc.load_balanced_view(), rc.ids I get "[]" as output (on the head node). Installing telnet on the slave nodes makes no difference.

Comment: `telnet` has nothing to do with `IPython`, it is just for testing if you are able to connect. So, launch `ipcontroller --port=8888`, then check it works by doing `telnet localhost 8888`, I get `Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.`, it means it is successful. Then try from the computing node `telnet IPOFLOGINNODE 8888`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your patience. It seems the port is not being opened when launched through `mpirun ipengine` but is opened with `ipcontroller`. I've updated the question with the full details. Sorry to take so much of your time over this, but if you have any ideas, I'd be happy to hear them. Thank you.